# How to get smtp address of current Outlook store

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

We have user with 3-4 shared email address in Outlook.
I am developing add-in where it will extract the email address of selected store and will get it's contact folder from People.

My problem is I don't know how to get email address of SelectedStore.
Here is my code.

```
            string recipientName = SelectedStore.EmailAddress; // This is what I want to make it work

            Outlook.Recipient recip = ns.CreateRecipient(recipientName);
            recip.Resolve();

            if (recip.Resolved)
            {
                Outlook.MAPIFolder folderContacts = ns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recip, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);
            }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For the mailbox owner, you can either try to read the `MAPIFolder.Store` property to get to the parent store, then read the `PR_MAILBOX_OWNER_ENTRYID` property (DASL name `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x661B0102"`) using `Store.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty`. You can then use the store owner entry id to call `Namespace.GetAddressEntryFromID`. Once you have the `AddressEntry` object, you can use `AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress`.

Note that `PR_MAILBOX_OWNER_ENTRYID` property is only available in the online stores. You might want to use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) and its [RDOExchangeMailboxStore](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdostore.htm#RDOExchangeMailboxStore).`Owner.SmtpAddress` property. `RDOExchangeMailboxStore` can be retrieved using `RDOSession.GetRDOObjectfromOutlookObject(Store)` or using `RDOSession.GetStoreFromID`.

You can also try to retrieve the store entry id and parse it - its format is documented and you can extract the EX type address of the owner. You can then construct the GAL entry id to open the `AddressEntry` object. From there, you can retrieve the SMTP address.

Answer (score 0):

Just to let you know, I found the solution.

`Outlook.MAPIFolder folderContacts = store.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);`

should do the trick.

Comment: How would opening the Contacts folder from a particular store help you retrieve the store owner's SMTP address?

Comment: Apologies, my bad. I should have explained properly. My main problem was, to fetch particular store's address book. So what I was trying to do is, get `selectedStore`'s email address and use it to look for address book. Then I figure it out I can do the same with above code i.e. fetching the contacts.